# Is it possible for null-conditionals to not return nullable value types while checking conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, null-conditional-operator

When assigning a value from a null-conditional, *it makes sense* to return a nullable value type.  Otherwise, if the object is null, the null-conditional would return the value type's default and you don't want that.  Therefore, this is good:

```
bool? IsTerminated = Employee?.IsTerminated;
```

However, why does it return a nullable type if I am just checking a condition?  You would think that the compiler could figure this out just fine:

```
if (Employee?.IsTerminated) { /*do something here*/ }
```

After all, it's just compiling down to this, right?

```
if (Employee != null && Employee.IsTerminated) { /*do something here*/ }
```

In order to get it to work, I have to do this:

```
if ((Employee?.IsTerminated).GetValueOrDefault()) { /*do something here*/ }
```

Between the extra code and having to wrap the expression in parens, the whole purpose of the null-conditional's short-hand syntax appears to be defeated.  Is this the proper way to handle a null-conditional return value or is there another way that doesn't involve accounting for a nullable return value?

Comment: You can use `if (Employee?.IsTerminated == true)` instead of `GetValueOrDefault`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A?.B` contains `B` of a reference type, then you'll get a return of type `B`.  Otherwise, if `B` is a value type, the return type is a nullable wrapping around type `B`.  So, that's a short answer to your question.

With that being said, in your case, since you're getting back a `bool`, it's understandable that it'll be wrapped as `bool?`.  Knowing that, you should simply work with it as you would normally would with `bool?`.  One way is to simply do an equality comparison to a desired value of `bool`.

For example:

```
if (Employee?.IsTerminated == true) { }
```

It's a bit shorter and easier to read than:

```
if ((Employee?.IsTerminated).GetValueOrDefault()) {  }
```

The example comparison works, because `null` will never equal to a `bool`.

Comment: So it turns out to only be an issue with Booleans, and probably because of the differences between binary expressions (an comparison operator between two expressions) and a Boolean expression that implies an equality operator.  Certainly much better than the way I've been doing it.

Comment: language architects [are aware of this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/784), maybe if we're lucky we will someday get a possibility to redefine the operator so that we could do the more intuitive `bool b = foo?.booleanproperty`. IMHO and knowing both sides of the argument, this really should be the default behavior *because it is convenient*.

Comment: @dlatikay To each is own, I guess. To me, this is more intuitive: `bool? b = foo?.booleanproperty`. That's because if `foo` is `null`, I would expect `b` to be `null`; otherwise, I would expect a `bool`. Thus, a nullable `bool` makes perfect sense. I guess what you're suggesting is that if `foo` is `null` then `b` would be `false`? I can see the attraction of such implicit conversion, but that would actually take away some freedom in deciding what to do with the value. If `foo` is `null`, I would like to know it in some scenarios, so that my code can handle it properly, instead of masking it.

Comment: @dlatikay I guess the way to handle this would be to allow the programmer to choose whether the result is `bool` or `bool?`, based on their particular needs, and convert `null` to `false` if `bool` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the **null coalesce operator**:

```
if (Employee?.IsTerminated ?? false) { /*do something here*/ }
```